# Replacing characters with regular exp

Tags: php, regex

Let's say i have a variable which is coming from form.

```
$number = $_REQUEST['number'];
```

It can have only three types of values.

```
1. 9***2331**32
2. 9%%132%%13%%
3. 3xxx31231xx4
```

So only `*,%,x`

How can i replace the wildcards with regular exp to `'_'`

Comment: Why not just do a string replace, then?

Comment: I have read a bit about regular exp, but havent understood much

Comment: just google php string replace, regex is for matching patterns you are trying to replace single characters which is completely trivial.

Comment: Grant - using str_replace will need 3 if statements

Comment: So? Clarity is king, not lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$number = str_replace(array('*','%','x'),"_",$number);
```

This replaces every '*,%,x' with '_'

P.S: Check the [manual](https://www.php.net/str_replace)

Answer (score 0):

```
$output = preg_replace("/[*%x]+?/", "_", $input_lines);
```

Using your example, you will get this:

```
1. 9___2331__32
2. 9__132__13__
3. 3___31231__4
```

Comment: Close enough, but i need replace EVERY *%x. For example it is 8xxx92 it should be 8___92 not 8_92

Comment: Edited answer, try now.